# JQuery is not working after adding google translator to my page

Tags: jquery, html, google-translate

I have added the Google Translator to my website which I am developing website in HTML.
Now the mobile navigation menu is not working also the JQuery is not working to the pages.

Here is the link to my website: http://maverickbuzz.com/ekodio

Can somebody suggest me where i am wrong!

Here is the code which I have added to the website

```
 <li>
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                includedLanguages: 'de,en,ja,ko',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
            }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</li>
```

Comment: try to load script before HTML body `</body>` ends.

Answer (score 0):

try to add script before HTML body tag  ends.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>


<span>Lets Translate this</span>

<ul>
 <li>
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>   
 </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {

  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                includedLanguages: 'de,en,ja,ko',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
            }, 'google_translate_element');

}

</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not working, I have already added the code before the </body> tag.

Comment: You can view the source code. It's HTML page. The code is big in size cannot paste here in the comment...

Answer (score 0):

Always check the console for errors.

```
counter.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-ui-min1.11.2.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-1.12.0.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):37 GET http://maverickbuzz.com/ekodio/home/js/jquery-ui-min1.11.2.js 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see, your site can't load in your dependences such as jQuery because apparently they do not exist at the path you have specified.

Verify the files are in your folders and ensure the paths to said files are correct.

Comment: Hi Ashley, I have checked the resources and makes them correct but its not working.